# Redirection to services in NAT or Bridged Network only with one subdomain

Tags: webserver, port-forwarding, bridge, nat, dyndns

I have one subdomain (dyndns). xyz.dyndns.com (f.e.)
Here my question begins:

- I have a server for virtualisation.
- On the server I have multiple VMs
  where different web-services are available through https.
- My router is configured with xyz.dyndns.com
- VMs can be accessed over NAT or be Bridged to router

How is it possible to access VM_1's and VM_2's WebService like:
`https://xyz.dyndns.com/vm_1_webservice` or
`https://xyz.dyndns.com/vm_2_webservice`

Because I need to add redirection rules to router.
I know that with bridging the VMs I can simply redirect http to the VM on router.
In my local network I have configured anything with DNAT (iptables).
I.e. when I go trought localhost(server):40001(port) f.e. I will be redirected to VM_1's WebService which is accessible through SSL. Like:
`https://127.0.0.1:40001/vm_1_webservice`
It works good. How to go on?(with nginx or apache on host?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical approach is to setup a web server such as Nginx or Apache on either the router/switch box, or have the router/switch box redirect ports 80 & 443 to a internal host that's running Nginx or Apache.

Once traffic has been setup so that it's passing to a web server, you can then setup virtual hosts within the web server, which can take care to route the traffic to the appropriate vm1_webservice, vm2_webservice, etc.

#### Nginx

I'll show you 1 basic Nginx method but you can get very elaborate with these rules once you grok how it works. Also take a look at this tutorial titled: [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) which shows how you can configure Nginx to service multiple sites on a single port 80/443.

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4567/;
  }
}

server {
  server_name www.example2.com
  location {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4568/;
  }
}
```

You'd change the proxy_pass lines to match whatever port @ host your vm1_webservice was running on, for example.

Comment: @x4k3p - you're quite welcome, thanks for the Q.